# Open source Windows file explorer that supports long paths (over 260 characters)

Tags: windows, open-source, file-management, long-paths

Windows 10 can support long paths [after flipping a bit in the registry](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/).

Unfortunately, developers have to make their programs long-paths-aware, and [Explorer++](https://github.com/derceg/explorerplusplus) is not long-paths-aware ([2016 issue](https://github.com/derceg/explorerplusplus/issues/60)).

Is there a graphical file manager for Windows that supports long paths and is open source?